# time complexity and space complexity of a function with binary search

Tags: java, time-complexity, binary-search, space-complexity

I wrote the following function in `Java`;

```
int foo(int a[], int n) {
    int num1 = 1, num2 = 1; 
    while(num1 < n) {
        if (binarySearch(a,num1,num2) >= 0) {
            return num2;
        }
        num1 = 2 * num1;
        num2 = 2 * num2;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to figure out the time complexity and space complexity of this function. I know that the time complexity of `binarySearch` is `O(logn)` and space complexity of this function is `O(1)`. With this information, I tried to calculate those things from of `foo` function. I think that the time complexity of `foo` is `O((logn)^2)` and space complexity is `O(1)` but I am not sure about it. What is the best method to calculate those things?

Comment: What is the time complexity of the outer while loop? Start with the assumption that binarySearch() is `O(1)` to analyze this. Then when you have an answer, multiply the two.

Comment: What does `binarySearch(a,num1,num2)` do? And, since `num1` and `num2` always have the same value (I mean, `num1=num2`), why not using one variable only?

Answer (score 0):

Let's analyze a simplified `while` loop without the `binarySearch()` call:

```
while(num1 < n) {
    num1 = 2 * num1;
}
```

How many steps does this take as a function of `n`?

Once you answer this question, the key to a final solution is to realize that the complexity of a while loop multiplies by the complexity of its body. This means that the final answer is the answer to the above question time `log n`.

Comment: thank you for you replay. For the while loop, the time complexity is `log n` and because `binarySeach` is also `log n`, the time complexity of `foo` is `log(n) * log(n) = (log(n))^2)` is it correct?

Comment: @vesii Yes, that is my analysis as well.